# How should I parse this json object in react with lifecycle method?

Tags: json, reactjs

How should I parse this using lifecycle methods?

```
{"blocks":[{
  "key":"33du7",
  "text":"Hello there!",
  "type":"unstyled",
  "depth":0,
  "inlineStyleRanges":[],
  "entityRanges":[],
  "data":{}}],
  "entityMap":{}
}
```

I want to render the text in my component but I don't know why it throws undefined error. How should I call it?

This is my component:

```
class Blog extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.blogContent = props.blogContent;
    this.blogId = props.blogId;

    this.handleRemoveBlog = this.handleRemoveBlog.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        blog__: '',
    };

}

handleRemoveBlog(blogId){
    this.props.removeBlog(blogId);
}
```

This is my lifecycle method , I would use this.setState but first of all it's giving undefined in console.

```
   componentWillMount(){
      this.state.blog__ = JSON.parse(this.blogContent);
      console.log(this.state.blog__.text);    // this gives undefined     
  }
```

This is the render part..
The data is coming from Firebase.
And {this.blogcontent} gives that json string that I previously mentioned.

```
render(props) {
    return(
        <div className = "blog header">
            <p>{this.blog__.text}</p>

        </div>
    );
}
 }

 Blog.proptypes = {
    blogContent: Proptypes.string
 }
```

Comment: Please include the code that you have written to attempt using this object.

Comment: @brandNew is right. Simple answer - just based on your comments - use componentWillMount() and maybe also componentWillUpdate()

Comment: Sorry , I have updated it now. Now can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would mostly depend on where you are getting this object from. If it is fetched over the network then the best place to pass it is in the `componentDidMount`. The reason for this is that the alternative lifecyle method (`componentWillMount`) does not guarantee a re-render of your component since it does not wait for async actions to finish execution before passing control down to your render method. Hence `componentDidMount` is best because as soon as new `props` are received or `state` is changed it will trigger a re-render. However, if this object is pulled from within the application then chances are, it will work just fine even if pulled within `componentWillMount`. This is because that operation would be much quicker, so much that control would be passed down to the render method with the new `props`. This is not guaranteed especially if you want to set `state` in the process (setting state is also async, so control might execute the rest of the code before all the required data is received).

In short, pass this to `componentDidMount` and in your render function, before accessing this prop, make sure that it exists. That is, instead of

```
render() {
 return <div>{this.props.theObject.blocks[0].key}</div>
}
```

rather do:

```
render() {
 return <div>{this.props.theObject && this.props.theObject.blocks[0].key}</div>
}
```

This is how you would do it (assuming you are getting the file over the network using axios)

```
componentDidMount() {
   axios.get('url/to/the/file')
     .then(fileData => this.setState({
       data: fileData
     });
}
render() {
  // return whatever you want here and setting the inner html to what the state holds
}
```

Comment: So what should I write in componentDidMount if I want to get the text in that json string

Comment: What does this line means - this.props.theObject && this.props.theObject.blocks[0].key

Comment: It's lazy evaluation. Javascript and most other programming languages use it. What it does is evaluate the first expression, if the first expression is false it returns false because whether or not the following expression is true the end result is false because the two expressions are connected by an ampersand (&&). For example `false && true` returns `false`. While `false || true` returns true.

Comment: Thanks , got it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.setState({})` in your `componentWillMount` function instead assign the data to the variable. Also I recommend to use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` because it's getting deprecated in the future.

```
  componentDidMount(){
      let text = JSON.parse( this.blogContent );
      this.setState({blog__: text });     
  }
```

Edit: Only use setState in componentDidMount according to @brandNew comment

Comment: Using `setState` might not be a good idea since it is not a guarantee that the state will be set before the render method is executed. Also, the same goes for `ComponentWillMount`

Comment: @brandNew That should not be the problem. Render function will then called twice.

Comment: It is actually a problem because you are saying the poster must setState in ComponentWillMount. That's definitely a problem since it is not guaranteed that setState will finish before control is passed over to the next function

Comment: Ahh then is that problem. But you should always use componentDidMount()

Comment: Look at the first line of your answer. "Use this.setState({}) in your componentWillMount"

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify the state using

```
  this.state.blog__ = JSON.parse(this.blogContent);
```

The proper way to do it is using the `this.setState()` method:

```
  this.setState({blog__: JSON.parse(this.blogContent)})
```

Then, to ensure that the component will be re-rendered, use the method `shouldComponentUpdate()`:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState) {
    if(nextState != this.state) {
        this.forceUpdate()
    }
}
```

Take a look at the [State and Lifecycle docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Other point: Use `componentDidMount()` instead of `componentWillMount()`, because it will get deprecated in the future.

> Atention: The `setState()` is an asynchronous method. So, it won't instant update your state.