# How to read file in React js?

Tags: reactjs

i want to read csv file in reactJS. i am trying file system ('fs') but it is not working.

Below is my same working code in nodejs,but it i not working in ReactJs. can somebody guide me how to read file in React js. Do we have any simple method for this ? i just want to read file from same project directory.

Working code in node js

```
const CSVToJSON = require("csvtojson");
const CSVToCSV = require("jsontocsv");
const FileSystem = require("fs");

CSVToJSON().fromFile("./ca-500.csv").then(source => {
    console.log(source);
})
```

But when tried in React js it is giving below mentioned error

Error: Cannot find module 'fs'

Comment: By either bundling it in using a csv loader (e.g. you webpack it into your bundle), or by being nice to your users and network-fetching it only when you actually need it, using the Fetch API. If it's static CSV data, just convert it to a normal JS file and load _that_ instead using a plain require/import. Takes seconds in any modern code editor. Don't use entire libraries for on-the-fly conversion work that you can do yourself up front so you never even _need_ to convert any data.

Answer (score 1):

you can try `react-csv-reader`

`npm install --save react-csv-reader`

[example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-reader)

**Usage**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import CSVReader from 'react-csv-reader'

class App extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <CSVReader
        cssClass="csv-reader-input"
        label="Select CSV with secret Death Star statistics"
        onFileLoaded={this.handleForce}
        onError={this.handleDarkSideForce}
        inputId="ObiWan"
        inputStyle={{color: 'red'}}
      />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

**Alternatively** you can use `React File Reader`

`npm install react-file-reader --save`

```
<ReactFileReader handleFiles={this.handleFiles} fileTypes={'.csv'}>
    <button className='btn'>Upload</button>
</ReactFileReader>
```

```
handleFiles = files => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
    // Use reader.result
    alert(reader.result)
    }
  reader.readAsText(files[0]);
}
```

[example](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api)

If you just want **read a local file** you can use `papaparse`

`npm install papaparse`

```
import React from 'react';
import Papa from 'papaparse';

class DataController extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: []
        };

        this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getCsvData();
    }

    fetchCsv() {
        return fetch('./ca-500.csv').then(function (response) {
            let reader = response.body.getReader();
            let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

            return reader.read().then(function (result) {
                return decoder.decode(result.value);
            });
        });
    }

    getData(result) {
        this.setState({data: result.data});
    }

    async getCsvData() {
        let csvData = await this.fetchCsv();

        Papa.parse(csvData, {
            complete: this.getData
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section className="data-controller">
                ...
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default DataController;
```

Comment: its working but it is not showing the actual data on browser console, instead it is showing some html ,      "   "<!DOCTYPE html>" ]
​
1: Array [ "<html lang=\"en\">" ]
​
2: Array [ "  <head>" ]
​
3: Array [ "    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />" ]
​
4: Array [ "    <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"/favicon.ico\" />" ]
​
5: Array [ "    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width", " initial-scale=1\" />" ]
​
6: Array [ "    <meta name=\"theme-color\" content=\"#000000\" />" ]
​
7: Array [ 
DataController.js:46  "  like this

Answer (score 1):

i have found the correct solution. it was answered below some other question.
Here is the link to that question.

[How should I parse this json object in react with lifecycle method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50529599/how-should-i-parse-this-json-object-in-react-with-lifecycle-method)

and the correct working code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import './App.css';

import * as d3 from 'd3';

import data from './data_set/data.csv';

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

componentDidMount() {

    d3.csv(data).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }).catch(function(err) {
        throw err;
    })
}

render() {


    return ( 
             <div className = "App" >
              <div> Data Visualization </div> 
             </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use FileReader onload methods to read the file data

You can find this useful to handle files using File Reader in React [ReactJS File Reader](https://youtu.be/Z4SDez4WsVQ)